# do I need to close a scanner object everytime I use it?

Tags: java, object, resources

I mean in a program that takes input more than once, would I need to close the object after each use, or just after the last input? ****sorry noob here****

thanks for reading :)

Comment: If you are using it for input from *keyboard* the best approach will be to **never** close it.

Comment: in what case would you recommand closing it? / when do I need to worry about a resource leak

Comment: You really should close a scanner object once you are done using it.  This is good practice and guarantees no memory leak.  Memory leaks are more of an issue in programs that run for a long time or require a lot of dynamic memory.  Just think about an operating system, a memory leak would be detrimental.

Comment: When you work with actual files - close at the end. Quite honestly - once you progressed beyond basics, you wouldn't be using `Scanner` anyway.

Comment: are there any cons to (closing a scanner object) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close your scanner when you are done using it. This prevents memory leaks.

But you definitely don´t have to close it after every keyboard input.

Of course closing the object takes computing time but I don´t think you have to worry about this as a starter.